# Blender - Set blending mode(Porter-Duff) for a material

Tags: materials

I am using Blender as the 3d asset creation suite for my projects.
I have an exporter that is able to export mesh, materials, animations and skeletons.

In my home-grown engine, I want to render some materials with alpha blending.
Specifically, I with to be able to set one of the [Porter/Duff](http://keithp.com/~keithp/porterduff/p253-porter.pdf) operators to the materials.

Is there a way I can set this from within Blender?
All I can see is a tranlucency adjustment under material properties.

Is there a settings for alpha Blending mode?
Or should I use custom property?

Thanks in Advance,
-Valyannan.

Comment: You might be looking for material nodes.

Answer (score 4):

The *Blend Mode* in the material settings is only available when Render is set the to *Blender Game*:

[image]

For textures there are [Blend types](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Textures/Influence/Material/Blending_Modes) which are also available in the internal renderer.

I'm not sure whether you can map these properties to the required operators defined by Porter-Duff, thus custom properties could be a good alternative.